# how to use If to compare a number with an interval in python?

Tags: python

When I compile the Python code below, I do not have any output! my .csv file include numbers. like (80,100,50,40,250,300).

```
import csv
with open("duration.csv") as f:
 d1 = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f)] 

for x in d1:
 if 0<= x <200:
  print("0<=x<200")
```

any solution??

Comment: Could you explain the target of your code?

Comment: @LPK I have a csv file which include some numbers, I want to import the csv file and then make a comparison with interval [0 200]. if the number is in this interval print the interval. but I can get any outpu

Comment: If your question is completely answered, please tick any of the answer answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from your rows are read as strings by the `csv` module. You should convert `x` to integer and then apply some formatting:

```
if 0 <= int(x) < 200:
    print("0<={}<200".format(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, csv.reader() reads all values as string. You have to type cast them.

```
import csv
with open("duration.csv") as f: 
    d1 = [float(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

Comment: Up vote and accepting the answer is a way to say thanks on SO.